# How to implement a program that can sent email in linux with exchange server host(outbound.company.com)

Tags: python, linux, email, smtp

I want to implement the program which can sent email **automatically** at the given time everyday. And make the effect just like no-reply@amazon.com. 
 
I have tried a lot of solution ,but none of these solution work.
Who have this experience,**please give me a solution** . 
Thanks a lot !

```
my python code<br>

    import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


# you == recipient's email address
 me = "no-reply@companyname.com"


you = "IDabc@company.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via exchange sever SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('outbound.companyname.com')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: You don't need PHP for that. You need a `crontab` entry and of course you need to configure the mailing subsystem properly on your Linux server.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your guide. I know {crontab} can do the Repeat job. You mean I need to config mailing subsystem on linux server. So after that, is there any best practice to implement the sent email program

Comment: There are several utilities and libraries to send an email. (Notably, do you need full MIME or not, i.e. just send a single plain text?)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch a full MIME can meet my requirement

Comment: You have MIME libraries in many languages (Python, C++, Ocaml, ...) and you also have commands to deal with them. But perhaps you should first send a plain non-MIME-d email (at least to debug your procedures).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you so much. I have test the python code up in my windows pc. But it do not work at all . Is there any mistake with my python code? Did I miss some stuff?

Comment: If you aim a Linux system, install Linux on your laptop and learn how to sysadmin and code on it. Don't develop on Windows for a Linux target - it is much harder, and you need to acquire Linux skills.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your great insights! It's helpful

Answer (score 1):

Create an Exchange smtp connector that accepts annoymous log ins from your Linux host and allows that host to relay.  Then use that smtp ip/port from your Linux host.